# Is it possibble to extend Router from angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-router, es6-class

I'm implementing a router history in a service, and it has become cumbersome to always import my custom service and the angular built-in router. I decided to import the router directly in the service and then use as extension of it. The problem I'm facing now is the use case of my custom service:

```js
     this.customHistoryService.angularRouter.navigate(...);
```

This works fine. But it has only dislocated the problem. I wish now to extend the Router class from angular like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class RouterService extends Router {
    ...
    constructor() { super(); }
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that a Router super class needs it's 8 parameters to build, and at the service creation I have access to none of them. With this I have one major question and another one as alternative:

- Is it possible to extend the Router class ? If so, how can I get the passed parameters at the Router class creation ?
- Is there another way to add functionality to the Router class ?

Comment: You can do this but you should not. A better approach is to use the wrapper pattern as in `@Injectable() export class RouterService { constructor(readonly router: Router) {} navigate = this.router.navigate.bind(this.router); }` and then rename `RouterService` to something else so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why I shouldn't ? Is there no other to add functionality to the router from angular ?

Comment: Because you should prefer composition over inheritance. This goes double for angular framework builtin services